# Using copy() in php function

Tags: php, copy

As it stands I have my files being displayed in an array, I am trying to create a function to make a copy of the file in the users directory as it stands my function is as follows:

```
function copyFile($dir, $fileToCopy){
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dirHandle = opendir($dir)) {
       $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.', '..', '.htaccess'));
       if($files){
           foreach($files as $file){
               if($file === $fileToCopy) {
                  copy($dir."\\".$fileToCopy, $dir."\\");
                  $output = 'Successfully copied file: '.$fileToCopy;
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
return $output;
    }
    if(isset($_POST)){
echo copyFile($_SESSION['UserFolder'], $_POST['fileToCopy']);
}
```

The output is given when i click the button to copy the file but nothing happens with regards to the file being copied the buttons code is like so:

```
'<form action="MyFiles.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" value="'.$file.'" name="fileToCopy"/><input type="submit" value="Copy" name="copyButton"/></form>'
```

hope I explained well enough would love some feedback

Comment: You're copying the file to the same directory, but not giving it a new name. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: figured it might create newfile(1) didnt realise had to be implemented separately, ill try it now thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it isn't copying is due to you not giving it a new name, so essentially it is just overwriting the same file. Try adding 'copy' after it like so:

```
copy($dir."\\".$fileToCopy, $dir."\\".$fileToCopy."copy");
```